# Update multiple records in one DB call

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have around 10,000 records in a table. I get all the records in my code memory and do some processing and decide whether the processing was successful or not. Thus for each of the record, I need to update a column of type `BIT` to either 0 or 1.

After processing each item, I really do not want to hit the database each time but pass the bit values of all the records at once for update.

Is there a way to do so or any other approach which is efficient enough.

Comment: When you do all processing in memory, why you are using DB instead of data file? Or single binary record/cell in DB.

Comment: @i486 because the data in db is entered by another application on different platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

You can use that to handle inserting a large number of rows efficiently into a table on the database (e.g. a temporary one for this purpose). For your purposes, it sounds like that table should just have whatever key you are using to identify each row, along with the bit value.

Then you can execute an UPDATE command to merge that table with the original data.

This way, you pass all the data to the server in one operation (or at least a small number of operations...even with `SqlBulkCopy` you may find it advantageous to break a large update into batches), and then let SQL Server do the work of copying the bit values back to the original table.